# Бинарная совместимость DLL

Tags: c++, dll, совместимость

Я хочу дать пользователю возможность добавлять свои функции к моей программе в рантайме посредством подключения dll. Эти функции должны обрабатывать экземпляр класса полученный из моей программы, сам класс при этом находится в отдельном хедере доступном как из самой программы, так и из dll. Собственно, я краткий пример набросал, он заработал, но в гугле/so пишут что при компиляции dll и exe на разных компиляторах может что-то сломаться

так вот,

1. Могу ли я принимать в dll экземпляр класса через указатель из основной программы и быть уверен что я с ним смогу корректно работать при использовании разных компиляторов?
2. Я так понимаю, разные компиляторы могут создать разные представления одного и того же класса в памяти, поэтому передача класса/указателя_на_класс может сломать процесс работы с ним внутри dll, это так? Есть в таком случае вообще способы избежать этого?

Для **явного** связывания использую `LoadLibrary(...)` в exe и `extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) ...` в dll.

Comment: Я бы не советовал пытаться выставить наружу какие-то штуки из C++, особенно на Windows. Вот, [почитайте](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22797418/how-do-i-safely-pass-objects-especially-stl-objects-to-and-from-a-dll). Сделайте простой C-style интерфейс для ваших плагинов.

Comment: Чтобы это работало, компиляция должна быть не только с использованием строго одинаковых компиляторов, но и с использованием одинаковых либо 100% совместимых настроек.